# Razor DropDownListFor sets selected value when I have no value set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have three `DropDownListFor` helpers in my view. All three of them use the same `List<SelectListItem>` as their 'options' parameter. The 1st and 3rd `DropDownListFor` contain an integer value that comes from my Model and the 2nd `DropDownListFor` has a `null` value coming from my Model. Naturally, I'd expect the 2nd dropdown list to have no option selected and fall back to its default 'Please select' option. But this doesn't happen. Every time I send a `null` value to the 2nd dropdown, it gets set to the same selected option as the one before it (the 1st one).

Here's what my simplified code looks like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstId)
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FirstId, Model.SelectOptions, "Please select")
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SecondId)
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SecondId, Model.SelectOptions, "Please select")
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ThirdId)
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ThirdId, Model.SelectOptions, "Please select")
    </div>
</div>
```

The only difference in the `Id`s is that the 1st and 3rd are `int` and the 2nd is a nullable `int`. Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT:

Here's how I'm constructing my `SelectOptions`:

```
model.SelectOptions.AddRange(db.SelectOptions.ToList().Select(option => new SelectListItem { Text = option.Name, Value = option.Id.ToString() }));
```

Comment: Did you tryto copy the Model.SelectOptions for each dropdown?

Comment: The default behavior is that if `SecondId = null` then the `Please select` label option will be selected so there is some other issue here. How are you constructing your `SelectList`?

Comment: Nothing wrong there, although you could simplify it by making the property `public Select SelectOptions { get; set; }` and using `model.SelectOptions = new SelectList(db.SelectOptions, "ID", "Name")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'll have to do some deep debugging to find what the issue may be. Thought it might be some quirk of Razor but I guess I've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps start by just adding `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecondId)` so you can check the actual value when the view is rendered

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just did. Everything went as expected. The 1st and 3rd TextBox showed their Id and the 2nd was empty.

Comment: I've just recreated your view with some dummy options and it works fine. If `int? SecondId = null` then the "Please select" label option is displayed (and the other 2 displayed the option based on the value of the property) so must be something else at play.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not sure. When I move with the debugger through the view, the moment I pass the 1st dropdown its `Model.SelectOptions` has the correct `SelectListItem`'s `Selected` value set to true, this same item continues to be selected through the 2nd dropdown and then again its proper `SelectListItem` is selected on the 3rd `Model.SelectOptions`. It's like nothing changes in the `SelectOptions` list between the rendering of the 1st and 3rd dropdown.

Comment: Weird! I cant reproduce it (using MVC 4). My 2nd `<select>` has no `selected="selected"` attribute whereas the 1st and 3rd have them on the respective options.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I also use MVC 4 here. I tried it with other records in the database and everywhere when the `SecondId` is null the dropdown sets to the same value as the `FirstId`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your code for view shares `Model.SelectOptions` object by three dropdowns, the `Selected` property on each `SelectListItem` object in the list may be interfered.

In your example, when first dropdown is constructed, one of `SelectListItem` object of which value matches `Model.FirstId` value will be set to `true`. On second dropdown creation, as `Model.SecondId` is null which does not exist in `Model.SelectOptions` list, SelectListItem with `Selected=True` will continue to be selected. Then third dropdown, since the `Model.ThirdId` has value that exists in the list, again the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` with the value will turn to `true` and selected.

In order to resolve this, I would pass new SelectList object to each DropDown:

```
@Html.FropDownListFor(m => m.FirstId, new SelectList(Model.SelectOptions, "Value", "Text"), "Please Select")
@Html.FropDownListFor(m => m.SecondId, new SelectList(Model.SelectOptions, "Value", "Text"), "Please Select")
@Html.FropDownListFor(m => m.ThirdId, new SelectList(Model.SelectOptions, "Value", "Text"), "Please Select")
```

Assuming none of `SelectListItem.Selected` in `Model.SelectOptions` is set to true.

Comment: I knew what was happening but I didn't have any idea how to go around it. This worked for me. Thanks.